# Detect store with proxy saving failure

Tags: extjs, callback, extjs4

How could I detect, that store saving is failed due to `500` response code?
I'm using direct proxy with php/json.

More broader question is: how could I know. which callbacks are available and what are conditions for triggering them. I looked at documentation of `Store` and looked through the Store's code, but with no success.

For example, `success` and `callback` do work for me, but `error` doesn't.

```
item.destroy({ // removing a model item
    success: function() {
        cont.ownerCt.remove(cont);
    },

...

var bRef = this;
s.save({ // saving store
    callback: function() {
        bRef.enable();
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know what kind of callbacks are available look at the ExtJs docs. For example for Ext.data.Model.destroy() method it states:

```
Parameters 
options : Object Options to pass to the proxy. Config object for Ext.data.Operation.
```

If you look for Ext.data.Operation config section you will find the following:

```
action : String The action being performed by this Operation
batch : Ext.data.Batch The batch that this Operation is a part of.
...
etc
```

How are you trying to detect 500 errors? Have you looked at Ext.Ajax events? I think it has global event `requestexception` where you can get all this information.

Comment: This helps, but I can't see `success` there. Is another class used for delete command with proxies?

Comment: You need to delete record from the store? Use remove() method. And if your store is autoSync subscribe to the store's 'write' event.

Comment: I need to remove them, as well as in any CRUD system.